# Code Eval Challenge #20

Tags: python

I joined code eval to improve my Python 3.5 programming.  Code Eval is a website, which offers challenges to any programmer looking to improve their skills.  Currently, I'm stumped on challenge #20.

---

Challenge #20 indicates that it needs the following:

Given a string write a program to convert it into lowercase.

INPUT SAMPLE:

The first argument will be a path to a filename containing sentences, one per line. You can assume all characters are from the english language. E.g.

HELLO CODEEVAL
This is some text
OUTPUT SAMPLE:

Print to stdout, the lowercase version of the sentence, each on a new line. E.g.

hello codeeval
this is some text

---

I wrote the program for Code Eval.  The strangest thing happened is that I received an error after submitting my file.  Here's what I programmed in Python 3.5:

```
>Python 3.5 Code
>Code Eval Challenge #20
>t3xx3r
>
>text1 = "HELLO THIS IS CODEEVAL"
>text2 = "This is some text"
>
>print(text1.lower() + '\n' + text2.lower())
```

I successfully submitted my third revision.  It ended up with a "Failed" icon.  It seems that I did not understand the Code Eval Challenge.  What was I missing that did not fulfill their requirement(s)?

My first revision was partially 'filled' for Code Eval but here is my first revision which was an actual partial success:

```
>__author__ = 't3xx3r'
>
>text = 'HELLO CODEEVAL'
>print(text.lower())
```

Yes, once again, so how did I get a partially successful code in revision 1 but not in the other revision?

I'm currently learning Programming Logic and will be moving on to Programming Fundamentals I & II.  The most difficult thing about Code Eval is that they're asking for arguments (which are enclosed within functions, methods, etc.) but I can't seem to find a way to successfully fulfill that challenge!

Comment: do you happen to know how they grade this? i feel like you should be writing a function that takes in ANY string and prints the lower cased version

Comment: "First argument is a path to a filename" - I'm not seeing that you've actually done any argument or file handling.

Comment: @Texan Polygynist: if my answer helped you, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @RNar No, I don't.  I'm relatively new to codeeval so it's been quite a while.  The function is already pre-made by codeeval and since jermenkoo provided some understanding of how it worked, I finally realized that codeeval created the function themselves to output the answer.

Comment: @jermenkoo thanks for providing assistance.  Your answer solved the problem and gave me points in codeeval.

Comment: @TexanPolygynist: could you please accept it? That way it will be marked as solved. (and we both gain reputation)

Here is how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic code you could write:

```
import sys

test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    print(test.lower())

test_cases.close()
```

Explanation: to access the first argument passed to the program, we need to use `sys.argv`; index is `1` because at position `0` is the running path of the script.

We iterate through each line in the file and print it in lower-case calling the `lower()` method.

Finally we close the file to prevent wasting system resources by keeping the file handle open.